# To stick or to switch topics

Tags: changing-fields, research-topic

I'm currently starting my PhD and I'm contemplating whether I should stay with my current advisor and topic or switch before its too late.

Current subfield

- The recent work in this subfield has been very cool and my advisor's strong track record in this area was what attracted me to his lab.
- I don't have much of a background in this field. I feel like I'm struggling when I do research in this field, and I'm not sure how effective I would be if I went into this long term. (I don't think I'm playing to my strengths if I entered this subfield).
- I have heard from others that academic job prospects in this subfield are lower than other areas.

Other subfields

- I feel more comfortable with other subfields and I think I would be playing more toward my strengths even in certain other subfields where I have less of a background.
- The labs in other subfields are more popular amongst grad students, and I suspect each student gets less attention than they would with my current advisor.

Any advice on whether to stay and switch? Is it best to wait and switch, or switch ASAP.

Comment: They say *a bird in the hand is worth two in the bush*.  Meaning, scope out possible projects/advisors before burning your bridges.  Really, it is very difficult to weigh the options here, because one of your options (change subfield) is totally at the fantasy stage right now.  Well, a fantasy is a starting point -- now try to flesh it out and build it into an actual option to weigh!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let me react to some specific comments

*I don't have much of a background in this field. I feel like I'm struggling when I do research in this field, and I'm not sure how effective I would be if I went into this long term. (I don't think I'm playing to my strengths if I entered this subfield).*

If you're just starting your Phd, I'd be surprised if you were an expert in the field, no offense. There is much to learn, and most early grad students - good and bad - feel they're struggling. The important question is are you struggling because it's complicated (good!) or because you don't care about the topic (bad!). If the latter, consider switching.

*I feel more comfortable with other subfields and I think I would be playing more toward my strengths even in certain other subfields where I have less of a background.*

One's comfort zone is seldom where significant progress is made. Again, if it's an interest issue, consider changing, but if you just feel overwhelmed by a new research area, consider embracing it - you will learn a lot. Moreover, perhaps you can bring your 'other sub fields' strengths to bear on your current subfield. Some of the best students I've known have used analyses and thought processes foreign to their immediate field.

*The labs in other subfields are more popular amongst grad students, and I suspect each student gets less attention than they would with my current advisor.
Any advice on whether to stay and switch? Is it best to wait and switch, or switch ASAP.*

If you're set on switching, do it asap. Just make sure your motivation is sound. You want to be able to stand out, for sure, but every field is going to have difficulties. It's a Phd.  If it were easy, everyone would have one.

Comment: Good answer.  (I upvoted it.)  I found this statement to be curious: "One's comfort zone is seldom where significant progress is made." I think that's true only in the sense that significant progress requires significant effort.  But the OP means that he is more comfortable with certain material/subjects than others.  I certainly think that most of the time, significant progress is made by people who are strongest / most comfortable / most expert in that particular subfield.

Answer (score 0):

The best advice is to select a topic based on your knowledge, backgrounds and your interest.

Do not rely strongly on your advisor expert, because this is your thesis, not his(her) duty.